# Dua's to recite while praying.

Tags: salat, dua

I'm a 20 year old guy. I have many doubts about what dua's to be read while praying. I am ashamed to clarify it with the elders here because of my age. Can anyone please tell me what dua's to recite after attahiyaat while we sit down in the last rakah.

Comment: that was just a quick prayer guide lookup thing, i wonder you posted this question here.

Comment: Well I found different things on 2 different sites. And didn't want to be confused. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: Alright, let me try to tell what i know.

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

In last tashudd of your prayer, afer reciting atahayat and darood-e-ibrahimi, you are supposed to make duas/prayers.

**These duas should be in arabic, can be in your own wordings too, there are plenty of sunnah prayers for this, should prefer them, some has special attributes.** Some are below.

### First dua:

> Ibn 'Abbas reported that the **Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to teach them
>   this supplication (in the same spirit) with which he used to teach
>   them a surah of the Qur'an.**
>
> "‏ **اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ عَذَابِ الْقَبْرِ وَأَعُوذُ
>   بِكَ مِنْ فِتْنَةِ الْمَسِيحِ الدَّجَّالِ، وَأَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ
>   فِتْنَةِ الْمَحْيَا وَفِتْنَةِ الْمَمَاتِ، اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ
>   بِكَ مِنَ الْمَأْثَمِ وَالْمَغْرَمِ ‏"‏‏.** (Sahih al-Bukhari 832, 833/ Sahih Muslim 590)

The **above dua is very important** as the words of shabi explain, also it states in same hadees:

> Muslim b. Hajjaj said: It has reached me that Tawus said to his son:
>   Did you make this supplication in prayer? He said: No. (Upon this) he
>   (Tawus) said: Repeat the prayer.

So, this one is a must, **some scholars say this dua is wajib, but most of the scholars say it is mustahib.** Anyway, it is most important. *Also this dua is narated in some different wordings too, leading to same meaning.*

### **Another important one:**

> It was **narrated from Abu Bakr Siddiq that : he said to the Messenger
>   of Allah (saas): "Teach me a supplication which I can say during my
>   prayer."** He said:
>
> ‏ "‏ قُلِ **اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي ظَلَمْتُ نَفْسِي ظُلْمًا كَثِيرًا وَلاَ
>   يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ فَاغْفِرْ لِي مَغْفِرَةً مِنْ
>   عِنْدِكَ وَارْحَمْنِي إِنَّكَ أَنْتَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ ‏"‏** ‏.‏   [Sunan Ibn Majah 3835](http://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/34/9) and  [Sahih Muslim 2705 a](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/48/63)

also see [another long beautiful dua here](http://www.sunnah.com/nasai/13/128), and many more sunnah duas. Some [here](http://www.islamawareness.net/Dua/Fortress/024.html).

### **And than you can say any supplication.dua in arabic**:

> Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: the Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“When any one
>   of you recites the Tashahhud, let him seek refuge with Allaah from
>   four things – from the punishment of Hell, the punishment of the
>   grave, the trials of life and death, and the evils of the Dajjaal,
>   then let him pray for himself for whatever he wants.”** (Narrated by
>   al-Nasaa’i, 1293).

PS: *It should be noted that the best of guidance is the guidance of Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and the best of du’aa’s are those which are in accordance with the Sunnah of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him). The wording of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) is the best of wording, because he is the most knowledgeable of all people about the Arabic language, and the most eloquent in speech. Allaah enabled him to express the most profound of meanings in few words, which is called conciseness of speech.* [(words from here)](https://islamqa.info/en/7886)

### Allah knows best